# SQL Temp Table Cost 75% Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, temp-tables

I have been looking for ways to reduce this Table Insert cost down from 75%. The one way that I was thinking we be to create the temp table before the insert but that didnt help is there any other way to improve insert into Temp Table.

```
@StartDate date = null,
@EndDate date = null

IF @StartDate IS NULL AND @EndDate IS NULL
BEGIN
    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + -12, 0)
    SET @EndDate = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))


END

    SELECT CustomerId, LogDate, StartDate = @StartDate, EndDate = @EndDate
    INTO #Temp1
    FROM Log l
    where l.LogDate >= @StartDate and l.LogDate < dateadd(day, 1, @EndDate)

    select
    l.*,
    a.StateId, 
    a.CountryId
    into #Temp
    from #Temp1 l
    JOIN [Address] a ON a.CustomerId = l.CustomerId
```

[image]

Comment: How long does it take to run?

Comment: You have a table variable declared but you are creating a temp table. Also, do you really need to use a temp table? How many rows are being inserted? Is it the insert or the select statement that is slow?

Comment: Well its 75% of the batch which needs to be 100% in total so to reduce it you would need to increase it elsewhere, is there an issue your trying to fix?

Comment: Declare of a table var then populate of a #temp is a bit odd...if you are creating a temp table then populating it, create it as #temp not @temp.  What are you doing with this temp table?  (edit, Sean beat me to the comment.  If you want a more comprehensive solution here, you need to show more of your issue than just the temp table create)

Comment: Its takes about 60 seconds to run the temp table has about 5784344 rows

Comment: I am then creating an addition temp table that includes a join  select
 g.*,
 a.StateId, 
 a.CountryId
 into #Temp
 from #Temp1 g
 JOIN [Address] a ON a.CustomerId = g.CustomerId

Comment: Are you really want to insert inot `#Temp1` or `@Temp1`?

Comment: I'd also avoid the CASTs in the WHERE clause... create variables of the same type and set them to the correct value, so you don't have to invoke functions or conversions in the WHERE clause. That probably won't affect much, but it's a good practice to optimize the query.

Comment: Why are you doing those cast and dateadd for every row?  Do once up front.   date does not have a time component.

Comment: Please post the declaration for the temp table, any indexes, and anything else related to the temp table's behavior like triggers or constraints you may have added.